# survival model with semi competing risks

Tags: formula, survival-analysis, recurrence

I am doing a survival model with semi-competing risks, this is my code and I got this error
library(Formula)
library(SemiCompRisks)
scrdata <- X0_CRC_Final_04
names (scrdata)
1] "stage_site"          "intraction"

> form <- Formula(time_recurrence + delta_recurrence | time_survival + delta_survival ~  age_cat | age_cat | age_cat )
> Error in is.name(callee) && length(object) > 20 :
> 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

I ran this code with the lower version of the program, but I faced this error with version 4.3